# I am trying to ssh into my raspberry pi and send a file to it using SSHpass and scp

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, scp, sshpass

This is the command I have been using:

```
sshpass -p "raspberry" scp -r pi@10.0.0.125:/home/pi/Desktop/New C:/Users/Matt/Desktop/CSIndependantStudy/RaspberryPiJars/raspberryEncrypt.jar
```

Whenever I execute the command no errors show up and it seems like everything has worked. However the raspberryEncrypt.jar has not been transferred to my raspberry pi.

When I try it with just

```
 scp -r pi@10.0.0.125:/home/pi/Desktop/New C:/Users/Matt/Desktop/CSIndependantStudy/RaspberryPiJars/raspberryEncrypt.jar
```

I get prompted to enter the raspberry pi password and receive this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname c: Name or service not known
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the string `C:/Users/Matt/Desktop/CSIndependantStudy/` ssh is interpreting c as the host. Use a local path that doesn't include a windows drive letter, or colon since the colon is the separator between host and path in scp.

Comment: So: 
  /Users/Matt/Desktop/CSIndependantStudy/RaspberryPiJars/raspberryEncrypt.jar     I tried that and im getting /Users/Matt/Desktop/CSIndependantStudy/RaspberryPiJars/raspberryEncrypt.jar: No such file or directory

Comment: There wouldn't be. You need a valid path without colons, ie relative to the directory you are executing the command

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit more? I don't think Im understanding it

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Windows,  hence you have the colon interpreted by scp as a host. You need to specify the local path as relative to the directory of your command prompt, use cd to enter the directory the file is, and then  run the command specifying just the name on the windows machine

Comment: Yes I am using windows. I am also using putty to ssh into the raspberryPi then using that terminal to execute the command. I was under the impression that sshpass cannot be used from the command prompt right?

Comment: Do you have an ssh server running on the windows machine? I'm guessing not in which case you'll need to scp or pscp from the windows machine

Comment: I figured it out using this guide: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html the command ended up as pscp c:\Users\Matt\Desktop\CSIndependantStudy\RaspberryPiJars\raspberryEncrypt.jar pi@10.0.0.125:/home/pi/Desktop/New

Comment: Thank you for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem with the help of camelccc

Ended up using pscp, the command was:

```
pscp c:\Users\Matt\Desktop\CSIndependantStudy\RaspberryPiJars\raspberryEncrypt.jar pi@10.0.0.125:/home/pi/Desktop/New
```

followed this for a guide: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter5.html